# Archer to Archer Data Feed in RSA Archer

Tags: datafeed, archer, rsa-archer-grc

Need to create Archer to Archer Data Feed that should set value of two fields as NULL in a cross referenced application, if the value of a field is Approved in first field. I am not getting how can I send a NULL value to the fields through data feed??

Answer (score 3):

Archer doesn't have "NULL" value, but you still can get it done like this:
**Step 1. Calculation.** Open your data feed configuration and go to the source definition tab.  
Add a new field to the end of the list and make it calculated.
Add formula to check value of 1st field that present in the data source and if it is equal to "Approved" then return empty string.
Something like this
`=IF([field field] = VALUEOF([first field],[Approved]), "","SOMETHING ELSE")`
The key here is to have this calculation return an empty string when you need it - "".

I suggest you to test your calculation in the calculated field in the application before you put it in the calculated data source field.

**Step 2. Data feed mapping.** Now you need to map new calculated field in your data feed to the field you want to remove value from. Go to the mapping tab in your data feed configuration and map the field. Make sure to selection options "Replace value" and "Empty Values" - this way existing value will be replaced even with empty values.

Similar approach works for me in multiple data feeds.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use novalue() function in the calculation

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a concept of NULL in Archer. The closest you're probably going to get is blank/empty. To do that, in the Data Map tab of your data feed, click the edit icon under Actions column. Check the box that Empty Values should be populated rather than ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption is that what is in the question is the only task required by the data feed.

1. Create report with the filter set as First Field = Approved
2. Fields to display should contain tracking id (tracking ID which is configured to System ID) of the Target app along with the Tracking ID of the Cross-Reference App.
3. In Source Definition add new source and give it an adequate name as clear or Null if you want
4. Where it says Raw Data Field in the drop-down, update this to static. Leave the source as not configured or unconfigured.
5. Map this newsource to the 2 fields that you are trying to clear. In Options set to Replace and uncheck add unknown and set to populate empty values.
6. Map the Tracking ID of the Target app and map the Tracking ID of the cross-reference.
7. Set key field definition for both apps to the tracking id
8. Set data feed to update only. Remove checkmark for create

If your are doing more than just clearing the 2 fields, then 
Stan Utevski answer is mostly correct except you must have the field you are evaluating for "Approve" in the fields to display of your report. Otherwise the calculation will not validate.